# Trying to apply $ref from OpenAPI to my use case

Tags: swagger, openapi

So I am trying to apply `$ref` for my OpenApi docs, but I am not sure if I am applying it correctly, I have something that looks like this so far for one of my endpoints:

```
/**
 * @openapi
 * /api/v2/auth/permissions:
 *   get:
 *     description: Get permissions
 *     responses:
 *       200:
 *         description: Get permissions.
 *         content:
 *         application/json:
 *           schema:
 *             $ref: './model/permission.model'
 */
```

This only outputs the string string like so: `"string"`.

Let me know if you need to take a lookt at that model file or anything else.

The `permission.model.ts` file looks like this:

```
interface Permission {
  _id: ID,

  roleId?: string,
  userId?: number,
  groupId?: number
}

const PermissionSchemaFields: Record<keyof Permission, any> = {
  _id: Types.ObjectId,

  roleId: { type: String, required: false }
  userId: { type: Number, required: false }
  groupId: { type: Number, required: false }
}

const PermissionSchema = new Schema(
  PermissionSchemaFields,
  { timestamps: { createdAt: 'createdOn', updatedAt: 'updatedOn'}}
);

export {PermissionSchema, Permission}
```

Comment: What toolset are you using? Do you generate API spec from the code or code from the API spec?

Comment: @Sasha, I am using swagger-jsdoc. I posted the solution below, but if upon reading it you have an answer that improves upon mine, I am open to accepting other answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the mistake of thinking that I had to do something different in defining the `$ref` from what the docs said, but that part had to be the same like so:

```
/**
 * @openapi
 * /api/v2/auth/permissions:
 *   get:
 *     description: Get permissions
 *     responses:
 *       200:
 *         description: Get permissions.
 *         content:
 *         application/json:
 *           schema:
 *             $ref: '#/components/schemas/PermActionSchemaFields'
 */
```

And then in the `permaction.model.ts` file I still had to add another one of these commented out blocks above the `PermActionSchemaFields` function like so:

```
/**
* @openapi
* components:
*   schemas:
*     PermActionSchemaFields:
*       type: object
*       required:
*         - _id
*         - permActionType
*         - description
*         - createdOn
*         - updatedOn
*         - __v
*       properties:
*         schemaVersion:
*           type: string
*         _id:
*           type: string
*           description:
*         permActionType:
*           type: string
*           description:
*         description:
*           type: string
*           description:
*         createdOn:
*           type: string
*           description:
*         updatedOn:
*           type: string
*         __v:
*           type: number
*       example:
*         schemaVersion: 1
*         _id: post /api/v2/patients
*         permActionType: SyncApi
*         description: RESTful endpoint POST /api/v2/patients
*         createdOn: 2021-07-16T21:30:33.624Z
*         updatedOn: 2021-07-16T21:30:33.624Z
*         __v: 0
*/
```